# Stack Overflow на русском стал более активным сообществом, чем Super User!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи

Поздравляю, коллеги!

На этой неделе мы преодолели еще один знаменательный рубеж:

[image: Stack Overflow на русском активнее Super User]

Мы обогнали второй сайт [трилогии](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), по [количеству вопросов в день](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)! Мои поздравления!

Следующий большой шаг – [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), крупнейший мировой сайт вопросов и ответов об ОС Ubuntu. Чтобы сделать этот шаг, нам нужна поддержка каждого! Пожалуйста, подбадривайте коллег делиться знаниями с сообществом – задавать вопросы на сайте!

Comment: Задача максимум: обогнать enSO, чтобы под локализацией подразумевался перевод с русского на английский. Ну а там и Аляску вернуть можно будет :)

Comment: Главное, чтоб SE не решились cnSO открыть при этом.

Comment: Ура, товарищи! Теперь на Берлин, т. е. SO!

Comment: Вау) Поздравляю :) Го обгонять дальше :))

Comment: Мне кажется, что обгоняем за счет людей, которым лень поискать в уже заданных аналогичных вопросах или в гугле. Но победителей не судят :D

Comment: А мне кажется, что ещё за счёт того, что у нас тут всё в кучу - и dba, и codereview, и много чего ещё.

Comment: @i-one это было бы справедливо при более-менее равном количестве юзеров и визитов. А по ним ruSO проигрывает в разы.

Comment: Еще радует что в этой выборке у нас наибольший процент отвеченых вопросов!

Comment: @AndrewB на enSO процент хороших вопросов тоже очень маленький, при том они наплывают с такой скоростью что непонятно как это все модерят там

Comment: Обгоняем по количеству вопросов, но не ответов на них. Ну или сам спросил, сам ответил через пол дня

Comment: @JonnyManowar, зато по проценту отвеченных вопросов мы всё же выше первой тройки.

Comment: @JonnyManowar количество ответов не всегда переходит в качество. На англоязычном SO есть немало сверхпопулярных вопросов с десятками ответов, большинство из которых даны в попытке урвать репутации. Но в целом альтернативные ответы на один вопрос конечно полезны, так что мы могли бы поработать над этим показателем. :)

Comment: @MikhailV про "как модерят" - у них там, например, есть специальный чат про ревью и закрытие ответов, там довольно много участников.

Comment: А по качеству вопросов?