# "Закат Stack Overflow"

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow, раньше-было-лучше

Многие годы сайт Stack Overflow был одним из самых популярных ресурсов для программистов, пытающихся решить какую-то проблему. Поскольку вопросы, размещавшиеся на Stack Overflow, часто оказывались среди первых, которые выдавал Google в каком-либо поиске, относившемся к программированию, то пользователи массово приходили на сайт и начинали задавать свои собственные вопросы.

Но не кажется ли вам, что мы все "ожирнели" и стали, как чиновники, которые при власти в нашей стране пользуются привилегиями? Раньше SO был отличным местом, где последний новичок мог зайти, задать любой вопрос и получить на него вежливый ответ. Сейчас же, когда модераторы и пользователи с обширным доступом получили власть, новичкам стало не место на нашем сайте. Разве мы не должны помогать таким, что бы они могли задавать свои вопросы более ясно и получать знания в программировании для большего продвижения в программировании? Вместо этого, любой их вопрос поддаётся строжайшей критике и закрывается за дубликат, непонятную суть вопроса или общий вопрос. И конечно же, после такого какое желание вообще будет заходить сюда ещё раз и вообще программировать.

Недавно был инцидент, я имел неосторожность ответить на вопрос, который многим не понравился и за это на меня обрушился гнев всех пользователей и куча минусов. Но я был счастлив, потому что хотя бы одному новичку помогли на современном SO.

Более конкретно о всех проблемах написано на хабре: https://habrahabr.ru/post/311322/

Comment: Такие статьи выходят чуть ли не каждый год, после первой-второй годовщины SO. С тех пор так и закатывается.

Comment: @Nofate я помню в одной игре зависал раньше. там тоже не то что каждый год, каждый квартал писали что игра загибается и умрет скоро..... уж лет 6 пишут оно и то же...)

Comment: @Nofate [можно лишь закатить глаза на этот закат.](http://svopi.ru/uploads/posts/2016-02/1455990182_28.jpg)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, СО не загнется (и не загибается), но политика плюсиков-минусиков очень грубо говоря тут возведена как религия. Лично мне такое не нравится. Конечно, именно поэтому СО и не похож на какой-нибудь засаленный форум для бородатых прогеров с дизайном форумов uCoz, но всё-таки система оценки подстрекает на негатив постоянно.

Comment: @VostokSisters на негатив подстрекают всякие твердолобые новички, которые пишут непонятные низкокачественные ответы и пытаются в комментах доказать, что они зе бест))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, согласен полностью. Но такое чувство, что ты имел кого-то конкретного.

Comment: "Более конкретно о всех проблемах написано на хабре" - на хабре перевод статьи https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.91l89zi94, опубликованной в июле 2015.

Comment: @VostokSisters, разумеется конкретного, у большинства опытных юзеров so больше десятка таких конкретных на примете. Но мы добрые и терпимые к новичкам, поэтому стараемся в конкретных юзеров сильно фекалиями не кидаться а обсудить вопрос в общем)

Comment: Загнуться-то он не загнется, но согласен, что проблема вопросов существует. Причем, наверное это проблема не первых вопросов от совсем уж новичков, а проблема с тем, что человек, уже задавший несколько неудачных вопросов, опасается  задавать новые.

Comment: Могу еще добавить, что как-то не очень интересно тут стало теперь время проводить...

Comment: @avp с такими людьми связывается лично Николас и выдает им пожелания по написанию новых вопросов.

Comment: @avp это потому что политота в отдельный чат переехала наверное .. :)

Comment: @PashaPash, это шутка такая?

Comment: @PashaPash, никогда не видел и не слышал, что бы кому-то писали

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, боже, а когда ты начала только программировать, то не был твердолобым? Сразу гением стал :)

Comment: @avp Николас действительно отправляет дружеские рекомендации и ссылки всем, у кого сходу не получилось освоиться и разобраться.

Comment: @alexolut, не думаю. На самом деле интересных вопросов как-то мало стало. Мне кажется это из-за причин закрытия типа *слишком общий* и т.п. Да и требование поизучать тему перед тем, как задать  вопрос, наверное, приводит к тому, что стимул задавать его уже пропадает.

Comment: @Yuri это уже оффтоп, но... твердолобый != новичок ....посмотрите определение в поисковике, что значит это слово)

Comment: @avp нет, не шутка - в админку прилетает тревога "множество закрытых вопросов", и Николас лично пишет участнику письмо "Мы заметили, что вы задали большое количество вопросов, многие из которых были плохо приняты другими членами нашего сообщества". С довольно дружеским содержанием, советами и ссылками по теме :)

Comment: @PashaPash, понятно. А я о том, что в чатах задают вопросы (а иногда  и прямо говорят, что опасаются спрашивать такое на основном сайте)

Comment: @PashaPash на которое, некоторые все равно отвечают "а чо я такого сделал та?"

Comment: @Yuri, новички бывают разные. Бывают вежливые, культурные и которые реально пытаются разобраться и читают правила после намеков, бывают например "тащите мне код холопы" или например "три моих одинаковых вопроса закрыли как дубликаты. Задам-ка я четвертый" или "ты обозвал мой код плохим? Да как ты посмел, ничтожество?!"

Comment: @VostokSisters *политика плюсиков-минусиков очень грубо говоря тут возведена как религия* -- не понял, о чём вы. Плюсовать и минусовать можно кого угодно и за что угодно. В худшем случае система откатит большую серию голосов за конкретного пользователя, по подозрению в накрутке репы. Но кроме аннулирования только этих голосов ничего не произойдёт. Я б скорее сказал, что к этим плюсикам-минусикам слишком серьёзно относятся: к плюсикам за явный трэш, к минусикам к своим постам непонятно за что.

Comment: *я имел неосторожность ответить на вопрос, который многим не понравился и за это на меня обрушился гнев всех пользователей и куча минусов* -- у массовых минусов обычно есть вполне конкретные причины, обычно несколько. Видимо, много участников подумало, что вы оказали своим ответом медвежью услугу и только дезинформировали участника, даже если и правда пытались помочь. Я неоднократно наблюдал тут такую ситуацию. Без ссылки на конкретный вопрос это беспредметный разговор, я просто отмечаю, что минусы могли быть, и скорее всего были, за дело.

Comment: @D-side, они были за то, что я написал за пользователя код. Все подумали, что он просит всё за него написать. Я написал - он принял ответ, сказал спасибо, но пользователи минусы начали лить за то, что я ему помог

Comment: @Yuri так думаете вы. Как думали минусующие, вы не знаете. Кто-то мог поставить минус за низкое качество кода (вышеупомянутая медвежья услуга) и полное отсутствие объяснений о том, как он составлен (даже если ТСу это не надо). Кто-то мог поставить минус за то, что ответ абсолютно бесполезен всем кроме ТСа. А кто-то действительно мог оставить минус, порицая такую "помощь", из-за которой люди решают контрольные и сдают экзамены не зная материал и выполняют тестовые задания не будучи пригодными для работы. Это всё не противоречит правилам, минусы можно оставлять за что угодно. Предложения?

Comment: @D-side, знаю, как они подумали. Они же комментили..

Comment: @Yuri анонимность минусов несколько ломает ситуацию, можно оставить порицающий комментарий и не ставя минус :D

Comment: @Yuri, вот представьте гипотетическую ситуацию, пусть компания Х ищет себе джунов. К ним приходите Вы и приходит Вася Пупкин. Обоим дают тестовое задание. Вы пытаетесь сделать свое сами, делаете не до конца и стесняетесь показывать. Вас не взяли. Вася Пупкин ни шиша не знает вообще. Он просто вываливает условие задания на stackoverflow, у скажем Grundy оказывается хорошее настроение и он его делает) Вася Пупкин получает работу (сдает экзамен, курсы или что там) при нулевом скилле, Вы - валитесь при ненулевом скилле.

Comment: @Yuri, по-моему на таком гипотетическом примере негодование кажется более понятным (если что я на том ответе минуса не ставил как и плюса =))

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, так и надо этой гипотетической компании в такой гипотетической ситуации.

Comment: @avp, согласен, но это уже другйо вопрос)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: «[Почему очередь на закрытие забита нормальными вопросами?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2782/208074)».

Comment: @Yuri вот как раз достойный пример моих слов  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35355074#35355074 ...... он русский и на ruSO тоже не хуже бред несёт

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Дело в том, что если бы действительно был "закат" StackOverflow, то это бы отображалось на количественных показателях. То есть, это выливалось бы в массовый отток пользователей. К счастью, этого не наблюдаем.

Данную статью на хабре вижу скорей провокационной, чем соответствующей истине. Не спорю, что могли иметь места шероховатости, которые имеют место и здесь быть. Но всё часто решается очень даже справедливо и довольно оперативно.

Согласен с мыслью, что вопросы закрываются, чаще чем хотелось бы. Иногда действительно причина закрытия "притянута за уши". Это происходит не так и часто и вы можете каждый такой вопрос обсудить на мете на соответствие его правилам сайта. Но из-за нечастых случаев несправедливого закрытия не наступит "заката".

У вас много слишком общих формулировок: "все "ожирнели"", "новичкам стало не место на нашем сайте", "недавно был инцидент". Это так безлико — можно поконкретней? Давайте лучше рассмотрим на конкретных примерах. Мне не ясен ваш посыл: а если новичок действительно задал вопрос-"неформат", так что, его не следует закрывать, просто потому что мы можем травмировать тонкую натуру новичка? Я намного чаще вижу, что даже на вопросах-неформатах новичкам терпеливо подсказывают направления и кидают ссылки.

Что плохого в справедливом закрытии? Если вопрос является дубликатом, то это не страшно для новичка, так как он получает ответы. Если есть какие-то другие нюансы, то можно вопрос подредактировать и переоткрыть или задать новый.

А обижаться можно на что угодно. Даже на то, что не захотели бесплатно делать чью-то работу. Поэтому мотивация "чтобы не обидеть" считаю неудачной. Но я редко наблюдаю осознанные нарушения правил сайта здесь. И если с чем-то конкретным не согласны, то тогда об этом и пишите.

И вообще данный сайт скорее наполнен желающими помочь энтузиастами, чем какими-то троллями-неадекватами (поэтому я с данной статьёй категорически не согласен).

Answer (score 19):

Выскажусь как один из активно ноющих по поводу лояльности к ленивым вопросам:
Нет, аудитория увеличивается, значит заманиваем сюда больше, чем отпугиваем :)

`ru.SO` [растёт семимильными шагами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3793).
Да, когда-то будет спад и уравнивание, но пока это восход.

На счёт "жирных" (в смысле репы и возможностей): [@VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) - самый жирный кролик в наших степях, но стремится помочь каждому страждущему, иногда даже с излишним рвением (ИМХО).
А модераторов оспорить можно на тут, на мете, коллективом принимается, обычно, лучшее решение. Но модераторы редко ошибаются (но бывает), не зря выборы происходят.

Вопросы... Больная тема. Но вопросы типа [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623153) -- это перебор с любой точки зрения.
Направление на google встречается довольно редко, хоть на каждый первый-второй можно туда отсылать/давать ссылку на решение. Разве не признак лояльности?

Ну и наконец: всегда найдутся те, кто подумал что если он дал задание, ему его не выполнили - это "ожирение", [модераторский-произвол](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb), гонения на новичка.
И после они бегут жаловаться на мету или хабр.

Comment: На мой взгляд, всё же если сделать за кого — это две строки кода, то почему бы и нет:)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вот-вот. Тем более что раз решение такое короткое, то, как правило, оно может пригодится кому-то ещё в будущем. Да и на попытки выяснить в чем именно вопрошающий не смог в две строки кода уйдёт больше сил и времени. На мой взгляд, проблема в том, что непонятно, сколько строк кода можно считать допустимым, равно как и насколько сложные задачи можно считать приемлемыми без попыток автора вопроса их решить.

Comment: @Regent Да здесь проблема гораздно глубже — просто есть мания "А достаточно ли ты продемонстрировал усилий для решения этого вопроса?". Даже на простейшие вопросы начинаются реплики "Стыдно такое не знать/не нагуглить и т.д.". Да, не спорю, что бывают вопросы вроде "Мне надо такой-то сайт, помогите", и действительно на них только комментарием можно помочь и они действительно часто бесполезны для всех, кроме ТС. Но здесь просто феерический перебор. Не хотите отвечать — не надо. Но даже за ответ минус "чтобы не поощрять". Раз у остальных нету такой мании, то и других надо переделывать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, помогать интересно, но видеть откровенное "Мне лень, сделайте мне!" - желание помочь отпадает, даже если это только одна строчка. А вот неодобрение может быть включит желание сделать лучше. На вопросы, где автор приводит какие-то исследования, куски решения, пусть и неверного, редко кто отвечает неодобрением.

Comment: @Other а где граница между "откровенно лень" и "не хватает навыков"? И что насчет будущих читателей вопроса? И действительно ли нужно пытаться из всех сделать "настоящих программистов", которые смогут адекватно думать своей головой (в плане программирования)? И есть ли смысл требовать попыток от автора, если доходит до [такого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626085/sql-удалить-все-частичные-дублирования-определений)? Я, может, неправильно оценил ситуацию, но, на мой взгляд, "пробую так" в этом вопросе выглядит так, что добавлен он только чтобы не "докопались".

Answer (score 11):

Не знаю в тему ли я сейчас выскажусь, но попробую. Задал я как-то вопрос - [Какие существуют события?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623950/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F). Заминусовали. Для меня реально события делились на те, которые появляются в результате взаимодействия с пользователем в графическом интерфейсе и какие-то еще, о которых я и спросил. Было неприятно видеть минусы, пока ребята не подкинули свои соображения. В общем через минусы к более полному пониманию тоже можно двигаться. Не спросил бы, не узнал бы о событиях нечто большее. На что мне обижаться, цель вопросом достигнута. Желание задавать аналогичные вопросы не пропало. Это в конечном итоге мне нужно.

Критика, как бы неприятна она не была, под определенным углом может стать плюсом. Нельзя пройти лес знаний не цепляясь за ветки(иллюзии, критику, заблуждения).

Comment: Как раз этот пример минусования и говорит о "закате". Только не количественном а **качественном**. Не понимают сути вопроса и как следствие считают его плохим (и минусуют).

Comment: Касательно вопроса: (не минусовал) он слишком "общий". Все-таки SO это база прикладных знаний. процитирую: *"поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему и что хотите видеть в ответе."*

Comment: @TimurVI это как если бы вы пришли в строительный магазин и спросили "какие бывают железки?"

Comment: Вот и надо конкретно спрашивать что вам непонятно

Answer (score 2):

**Да не бывает плохих и хороших вопросов. Каждому свое сложно, важно и нужно…**

**Многие супер вопросы и супер ответы** после обновления операционной среды, среды разработки, языка программирования,… парадигмы программирования,… **становятся просто никчемным словесным мусором**, подлежащим безоговорочной утилизации… )

Многие, особенно "технические" вопросы со своими ответами-костылями со временем так же превращаются в пыль…

А вот поддержка, помощь в поиске решения, кооперация (взаимопомощь, дружба, братство, связи) - незыблемые (нетленные) ценности любого сообщества, его сила, мощь и продуктивность! Впрочем, как и в жизни (нормальной жизни)…

**SO** не плохо задуман, а над ошибками можно поработать.
Да и над русским языком надо поработать, а то закрывали раньше вопросы как не имеющие пользы... (я этим как то сильно возмутился), да если его задали, рьяно ищут ответ, грамотно сформулировали - он уже не может быть бесполезным.

И еще. **SO** призывает не бояться задавать вопросы, "не бойся показаться не компетентным, зато получишь ответ и прочие бонусы",……… но потом, люди злорадно минусуют тебя!!!… Что крайне не приятно и не понятно

P.S.
Оставаться на уровне вопросов-ответов и ковыряния в них - весьма примитивная форма существования, нужно продукты создавать !!!

А то что показатели растут - просто никто толковый еще не взялся сделать что-нибудь лучше... А мне пока некогда

P.P.S. 
Джордано Бруно тоже ставил "не полезные" вопросы... за что и был... публично сожжен злорадной публикой... )

Comment: `закрывали раньше вопросы как не имеющие пользы` — понимаете, на этот сайт приходит огромное количество народа по прямым ссылкам из выдачи поисковых систем. Поэтому мы (все активные участники) хотим, чтобы каждый вопрос был полезен далеко не только спрашивающему. Особенно при сегодняшних масштабах (229 вопросов в сутки; между прочим, по этому показателю [мы третьи среди всех Q&A сообществ сети StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)), когда на дачу сугубо индивидуальных рекомендаций не хватает ни времени, ни сил.

Comment: `И еще. SO призывает не бояться задавать вопросы... но бьет после этого порой, весьма, больно` — мы бьём за просьбы выполнить то или иное задание. Потому что это и не вопросы вовсе, а желание нахаляву получить готовый результат «под ключ».

Comment: `Многие ... после обновления операционной среды … становятся просто никчемным словесным мусором` — что не отменяет их востребованность в настоящее время, пока не будет выпущена следующая версия. Да и кто сказал, что после окончания официальной поддержки технология или программа тут же умирает? Люди до сих пор Windows XP пользуются, хотя ей уже семнадцать лет (что по меркам IT является древностью).

Comment: `Оставаться на уровне вопросов-ответов и ковыряния в них - весьма примитивная форма` — но в то же время достаточно эффективная. Подобный принцип был создан как противопоставление форумам с их длинными и малопродуктивными ветками обсуждений. [Вопрос — ответ, ничего лишнего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour). Пришёл из поисковой системы, перечитал все ответы с конкретными решениями, выбрал подходящий под конкретный случай, ушёл.