# Серьёзность сообщества на русском языке

Tags: обсуждение

Все больше текущих вопросов заставляют размышлять

> "Насколько серьезно автор задавал этот вопрос?"

Ожидание готовых решений это еще пол беды, с которыми мало-мальски справляются.

Но иногда появляются откровенные тролли, *вакансии*, кучи дубликатов. И, как мне кажется, это становится (ну или по крайней мере станет в ближайшем будущем) серьезной проблемой.

Все более некомпетентная аудитория задает (всё более некомпетентные) вопросы. Не знаю переживал ли западный SO эти проблемы, возможно тут чисто воспитание и менталитет.

Лично я считаю, что необходимо как-то более открыто доносить до пользователя **смысл** данного ресурса во время создания вопроса.

---

Возможно у меня конечно паранойя или я предвзято отношусь к *RU* сегменту в связи с чем два вопроса.

1. Замечаете ли вы деградацию **качества** вопросов?
2. Считаете ли вы это достаточно серьезной проблемой что бы принимать меры?

Comment: Старость -- это когда кажется, что раньше было лучше.

Comment: [Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/616/191482) - замечу, топик от 15-го года

Comment: Увеличивается популярность, посещаемость ресурса и как следствие количество простых вопросов. Это ни хорошо, ни плохо  - это данность. Это не значит, что нет вопросов сложнее. Плюс все новички со временем станут задавать вопросы сложнее. Вы можете не отвечать на простые вопросы - ответит кто-то ещё. Вы можете поискать что-то интересное из оставшегося без ответа. Или самому задать вопрос, который Вас мучает день, два, неделю или больше.

Comment: Не спрашивай, что ruSO может сделать для тебя, спроси, что ты можешь сделать для ruSO.

Comment: @МихаилРебров а к ruSO у меня вопросов нет. Я беспокоюсь о том что деградация качества вопросов может повлиять на общее качество ресурса. Т.к. более серьезные вопросы начнут задавать на enSO, ожидая здесь менее квалифицированную аудиторию.

К слову проблема в том что разные ресурсы не в самом верном контексте освещают SO, и новички ошибочно считают этот сайт площадкой гуру решающих все проблемы за них.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский грустно то что за 2 года так ничего и не поменялось. Или вы имеете в виду что вопрос дубликат?

Comment: @VasiliyRusin , как правило пользователи не решают задавать ли им вопрос на этом ресурсе всматриваясь в главную страницу ruSO и анализирую 20 последних вопросов...и по-моему отношение к ресурсу тоже не по первой странице складывается. Люди переходят сюда как правило из поисковых систем на вполне себе конкретные вопросы и ответы, которые(спасибо Гуглу) как правило соответствуют запросу пользователя. И если в течении какого-то времени пользователь решал свои задачи с помощью ruSO, он с большей степенью вероятности сможет задать на нём вопрос.

Comment: дубликат-недубликат)  ....`грустно то что за 2 года так ничего и не поменялось` - а как оно должно было поменяться? Как ruSO и вообще SO может повлиять на миллионы людей, которые задают вопросы? Подготовить легион людей, который будет разъезжать по миру и учить их уму разуму? Мне казалось этим занимаются родители и учителя/преподаватели. Причем тут вообще ruSO и некомпетентность задающих вопросы?

Comment: `более открыто доносить до пользователя смысл данного ресурса` - в чем смысл данного ресурса с вашей точки зрения? и как это противоречит тому, что есть сейчас? И какие конкретно у вас есть предложение по исправлению ситуации, которую считаете неправильной? Высвечивать окошко перед вопросом? Это решит проблему целиком и полностью?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну уж точно не в том что бы задавать вопросы [как сделать графику Crysis на winforms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/680703/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5) Я о том что нет ничего хорошего в том что народ не понимает, что это не самое лучшее место для шуток. И вы меня не поняли, я не говорю что проблема в ресурсе.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как решать эту проблему это уже отдельный вопрос. Здесь я пытаюсь понять видит ли сообщество эту проблему. `Это решит проблему целиком и полностью?)` Вы так говорите будто с вашей точки зрения, лучшее решение "свесить ножки" и вообще ничего не делать.

Comment: `ну уж точно не в том что бы задавать вопросы как сделать графику Crysis на winforms` - поэтому вопрос  закрыт и на нём минусы, а со временем и удалится. что не так?  `народ не понимает, что это не самое лучшее место для шуток` - так откуда такая информация, что человек шутит? если вам в голову такое не приходило, не значит, что не найдется кого-то еще)  `как решать эту проблему это уже отдельный вопрос.` - так может быть всё же стоит сразу и изложить что не так и как, по-вашему, стоит решить? А то пока не ясно зачем этот вопрос/обсуждение.

Comment: `будто с вашей точки зрения, лучшее решение "свесить ножки" и вообще ничего не делать` - пока вообще не ясно в чем проблема. в некомпетентных задающих? ну логично, большинство — новички. причем постоянно разные. те, кто остается в числе постоянных участников - учатся и уже не задают совсем плохих вопросов, а на вновь прибывающих как влиять? глобальным сеансом гипноза?)).... 
 или проблема в том, что кто-то спамит или троллит? такие вопросы закрываются или помечаются как спам или удаляются... так что пока ничего непонятно что вы пытаетесь сказать

Comment: Более того, даже откровенно тупые вопросы кто-то ещё и плюсует.

Comment: Почему речь только о русскоязычном коммьюнити, когда и [на большом so многие видят похожие проблемы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4770/213987)?

Comment: `Замечаете ли вы деградацию качества вопросов?` - многие сидят здесь года с 2011 (я например), особой деградации не заметно. С ответом от @edem полностью согласен.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin 99.9% аудитории ruSO абсолютные новички, напрочь лишенные желания думать и/или самостоятельно разбираться с проблемой. Смиритесь с этим и живите дальше.

Answer (score 20):

> 1. Замечаете ли вы деградацию качества вопросов?
> 2. Считаете ли вы это достаточно серьезной проблемой что бы принимать меры?

1. Нет, ибо деградировать может лишь что-то существующее, а подобного качества вопросы уже создаются в таком виде.
2. Это обычная ситуация для данного ресурса, в инструментарий которого **уже** заложены механизмы для борьбы с данными ситуациями: голоса против, тревоги, правки и т.п. Так что меры принимаются с момента основания сайта.

Answer (score 18):

> Ожидание готовых решений это еще пол беды

Да и готовые решения, примеры это часть обучения новичка, поэтому очень правильно что запрещены ответы типа "смотри документацию"

> откровенные тролли, вакансии, кучи дубликатов

С этим справится модерация

> Все более некомпетентная аудитория задает (всё более некомпетентные)
>   вопросы

Это естественно. Компетентная аудитория же не задаёт вопросы они и так знают как всё делать, либо способны найти ответ сами.

> Не знаю переживал ли западный SO эти проблемы

Там сейчас эти проблемы, откройте тег *PHP*, почти каждый вопрос заминусован, куча вопросов закрывается.

> необходимо как-то более открыто доносить до пользователя смысл данного
>   ресурса во время создания вопроса

Я так не считаю, каждый имеет право задать вопрос. Причём задать его так, как он может, как он его понимает, у вас же есть выбор отвечать или нет.

Answer (score 13):

Если Вы зайдете на англ. сообщество, то качество вопросов там тоже не сильно хорошее.

От плохих вопросов, как и от плохих ответов никто не застрахован.

Плохие вопросы появляются не потому что, что ресурс позволяет такое сделать, а из-за незнания, в большинстве случаев, самого английского, и как следствие, не умение работать с английской документацией.

И тут надо быть более лояльным.

Вопросы троллей или просто за плохие вопросы всегда можно проголосовать за закрытие, отметить тревогой.
А вакансии появляются, возможно потому, что на русском сообществе нет этого раздела, как на англ. версии.

Так же Вы всегда можете задать интересный вопрос сами, и поднять тем самым планку RU сообщества. Так делают многие в русскоязычном сообществе.

Answer (score 3):

Давно в сообществе 6-й год уже... Деградацию не замечаю, ну разве что с самого начала русское сообщество по сравнению с англоязычным более упадочное что ли с тяготением к самобичеванию и троллизму.

В начале меня это сильно расстраивало, но потом привык как-то и уже считаю это нашей как бы культурной особенностью что ли.

Comment: Принятие серой обыденности - что может быть хуже?

Comment: Конечно, борьба с ветряными мельницами и плевание против ветра - наше все - это тоже часть нашего культурного наследия - я это тоже принимаю :)

Comment: Что сразу так бесперспективно? Ужесточать надо, это можно, но ради стабильного потока юзеров, этим жертвуют.

Comment: @Aid давайте ужесточайте, я уже заметил какой у вас [перспективный ник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Аид)  :)

Comment: Расширять земли Мёртвых тоже надо :) А так, я достаточно активно пытался улучшать, всем (ответственным) на всё фиолетово.