# Русский SO умирает?

Tags: обсуждение, нытьё, раньше-было-лучше

Я, конечно, не активный пользователь ruSO, но мною замечена тенденция какого-то угасания в русском сегменте SO. Становится очень много вопросов без ответа. Взять тот же тостер, например, там просмотры у вопросов, грубо говоря, растут как на дрожжах, и ответ быстро находится, чего не скажешь в последнем времени о ruSO. Мне кажется, ruSO раньше был более живым что ли. А что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Сейчас к вам придёт _кое-кто_ со статистикой и как дважды два докажет, что всё хорошо, что посещения растут, приходит намного больше участников, чем уходит, и беспокоиться не о чем. (Сарказм, если что.)

Comment: И трава раньше зеленее была. Зря VlzdD ёрничает, ..неразборчиво.. Кстати здравая мысль - вооружитесь https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new и поищите подтверждения своим ощущениям ;-)

Comment: Всё очень субъективно

Comment: А в каком секторе сайта вы смотрели? Навскидку, те же [svg] и [c++] достаточно активные, без какого-либо спада. Ну а [vb6], к примеру, и так давно мёртв.

Comment: @Arhad, Вы бы ещё про Фортран сказали))

Comment: Верно замечено. Это от отсутствия интересных вопросов о реальной разработке и дискуссий в ответах к ним. Ну, не поощряется тут такое (SO не место для дискуссий, а заранее известные и однозначно верные ответы на новичковые вопросы о языке ... -- это из серии *`"песок неважная замена овсу"`*)

Comment: @avp, вынужден не согласиться, не думаю, что на тостере более интересные вопросы, однако человек с ответом находится в разы быстрее, по моим личным наблюдениям

Comment: Надо бы как-то точно привязать субъективный вопрос к точным цифрам. Например, показать, что на тостере (они не публикуют стату?) вопрос получает через час ответ с вероятностью 90%, а на ruso через час 90% вопросов оказывается закрытыми как "требует правки", а оставшиеся висят без ответа месяцами. И даже это будет показывать лишь то, что "so - база хороших вечных знаний, а не мгновенного ответа страждующим" (не все это разделяют, но такова официальная цель). А без цифр статистики это "[каждый год кто-то приходит и говорит о закате сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4770/213987)".

Comment: @vladimirch это смотря какой вопрос. Опять же, одни из топовых участников, которые хорошо знают свои технологии(я говорю про `java`, примеров думаю не надо) стали параллельно с SO сидеть на тостере. Ну, а на тостере по моим ощущениям(имхо) более легкие вопросы(и часто тупые). Не то чтобы на SO их нет, просто их сразу удаляют, и правильно(та же домашка, или элементарные вопросы, и т.п.).

Comment: Опять же по моим ощущениям - SO - более интересная площадка, чем Тостер. Потому что более прозрачная связь с администрацией(*хм*, со скепсисом скажут многие, и они правы) и более хорошее коммунити. Также на SO более хорошая система кастомизации, меток, и всего всего(имхо). Алсо, тут есть чатики(*хм* x3). Был бы признателен, если бы вы накидали какие есть плюсы у Тостера, которых нет у SO.

Comment: @avp да, кстати действительно интересных вопросов про разработку тут немного, и иногда хочется подискусировать. Но, как я заметил, самые интересные обсуждения про разработку собираются в профильных чатиках, в основном именно чатах по ЯП. Я не про SO чат, хотя там тоже иногда есть интересное, и не 4/26(хотя может потому что там нет комнаты которая мне интересна, а по C# там дискуссии идут), а например телеграмм чаты.

Comment: @VladD, пришёл со статистикой - Хьюстон, у нас проблемы (и это не сарказм).

Comment: На мои вопросы тоже никто не отвечает, даже мои конкурсы сегодня просто сгорели :(

Comment: @Arhad svg держится за счёт Александра, но с другой стороны метка не должна держаться за счёт 1-2 человек.

Comment: На основе обсуждения в каментах ниже, переформулировал бы в "enSO и ruSO превращаются в помойку плохих вопросов".

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev: Ну вот КМ какое-то время назад заявлял, что в ценности у нас «труд одного великого человека» не входит.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ: Вижу, спасибо! И всё-таки мой комментарий был правильным, только я ошибся в том, кто придёт.

Comment: Тег "нытьё" такая милота на фоне общей суровости модерации на этом сайте. :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1, ну учитывая то что на мете этот пользуется некоторой популярностью, почему бы не воспользоваться им =)

Comment: На мой вопрос, заданный здесь, ответили быстрее, чем на SO.com..

Comment: В основном что-то делаю на SO.com, здесь больше читаю, так вот там уровень вопросов и ответов гораздо серьёзнее, имхо. Тоже полно "как сделать мою домашку", конечно, но гуглят люди чаще на английском.   Сложно что-то сказать про статистику, но предполагаю пальцем в небо, что активность связана с теми, кто не сидит ни на форумах (такие ещё живы?), ни на иностранных ресурсах, динамика соответствующая. Возможно, если наблюдение верно, сейчас просто идёт период усиления расслоения между этими разными видами программистов.

Answer (score 22):

Проблема не у угасании, а в том, что за последние пару лет ничего не поменялось. Stack Overflow - это достаточно жесткий формат QA. Выйти за него в рамках сети Stack Exchange не получится. Нельзя перевести в формат форума, нельзя устраивать обсуждения за жизнь, почти ничего нельзя. Можно только отвечать на вопросы и делиться знаниями.

SO - это просто поток вопросов *разного* качества, но всегда достаточно простых. Да, иногда бывают технически сложные вопросы. Или технически интересные. Но формат всегда "У меня X - Делай Y!". Тут нет вопросов по архитектуре. Нет вопросов, ответ на который выходит за рамки "экран текста". Потому что такие вопросы - неформат.

Формат дает достаточно низкий порог входа. Любой разработчик с опытом может ответить на большую часть вопросов по своей метке. Это позволяет быстро втянуться и начать получать дофамин. Это как рубить монстров в диабле. Или убирать ряды в тетрисе.

Но при этом как бы круто вы не отвечали на вопросы - их сложность не растет. Более того, со временем каждый отвечающий осознает, что значительная часть задаваемых вопросов - очень низкого качества. Настолько низкого, что половина из них закрывается, а четверть - просто удаляется. И тогда участник начинает ныть, искать внешнее объяснение (домашки виноваты! администрация давит! это все бинайс! это все грубияны!). Или требовать развлечений. Или предлагать запретить простые вопросы вообще, силовыми методами.

На самом деле реальное положение не меняется. Меняются субъективные ощущения.

Какой из этого можно сделать вывод? Да вообще любой. Вот, на выбор

- SO был и будет наполовину заполнен плохими вопросами, и вы ничего ни сможете с этим сделать. Грусть, печаль, во всем виновата администрация. Ну или и пятая колонна. Или модераторы.
- SO был и будет наполовину заполнен хорошими вопросами, отвечая на которые вы действительно помогаете живым людям и делитесь знаниями. Солнце, весна, радость.

Полон или пуст стакан - решать лично вам. Это *личный* выбор каждого участника. Хотите получать дофамин - получайте. Не хотите - не получайте.

---

Для тех, кто таки любит счет.

Точную статистику выбрать достаточно тяжело - удаленные вопросы в [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) есть, но информации по наличии у них ответов - нет. В целом, по годам, выжили и получили ответы 62%/56.6%/52.3% вопросов за 2016/17/18 года.

Без ответа всегда остается 40% вопросов. Нет никаких "в полтора раза", нет никакой "удручающе картины", и нет "качественного прорыва". Есть количественный рост.

% за 2018 год еще вырастет - на сайте есть бот, который сносит неотвеченные вопросы старше года, так что часть низкокачественных вопросов, заданных в 2018, еще будет снесена. За 2019-й год считать статистику смысла нет (а тем более делать из нее выводы о росте или умирании). Нет никакого "ухудшения качества", просто старый мусор сожгли. Улучшения, впрочем, тоже нет.

Comment: Во многом здраво, но внесу пару уточнений. На so есть вопросы и по архитектуре (у них сообщество - у нас огороженные метки) и сложные вопросы тоже есть. Но у нас это дохло, потому что некому отвечать.

Comment: @AK на отдельном сообществе в сети - да, вполне могут быть вопросы по архитектуре. Потому что там ослаблены требования к общности вопроса. На enSo  и у нас - нет. Максимум - "что такое mvc". Ну ок, иногда ещё "как сделать свой репозиторий поверх ef". Это не вопрос по архитектуре, это уровень букваря :(

Comment: `Но при этом как бы круто вы не отвечали на вопросы - их сложность не растет.` -- в следствии согласия большинства с существующим форматом. А ведь в принципе, некая группа заинтересованных в совместном творчестве могла бы (даже в рамках существующего ПО, поддерживающего чаты) попробовать его изменить...

Comment: @avp его нельзя изменить на "не-qa" в рамках сети. Максимум - устраивать тематические посиделки в чатах. Или вживую. Было бы желание. Но на основном сайте все равно будет условие "любой может задать вопрос", а плохие вопросы задавать не запретишь.

Comment: @PashaPash, с возможностью любому задать   в том числе и плохой вопрос я никогда не собирался бороться. Речь ведь о том, что интересные "посиделки" куда-то канули (или просто конкретно мне они не попадаются уже давно?)

Comment: @avp: Ушли участники, которым было что сказать — исчезли и тематические посиделки

Comment: @avp да их и раньше особо не было. В чате, да, стало тише. Но чат на 10 активных участников - это не весь SO. Ну ок, заскучавшие участники пытались развлечься, начали делать code golf. Хватило совсем нанадолго. Кто-то просто ушел / стал неактивен. Я, например, почти не отвечаю последние пол года. По не зависящим от SO причинам. Просто я не лезу при этом в каждый вопрос на мете, и не рассказываю, как раньше было лучше (а на Хэшкоде было еще лучше!). Потому что понимаю, что раньше лучше не было. А многие - не понимают.

Comment: @VladD ну т.е. у нас что-то случилось в 2015-ом году(судя по графикам αλεχολυτ), исчезли посиделки? и с тех пор угасаем? уже 4 года, и все никак не угаснем?

Comment: @VladD давайте не переходить от шуток к обвинениям.  Могу в предыдущее сообщение смайлик добавить. Или удалить, если оно вас чем-то обидело. Удалил то, что вы посчитали выпадом. Сорри если что.

Comment: @VladD, вы правы. К сожалению, "общественно активная серость" побеждает (похоже, такой сейчас этап развития цивилизации)

Comment: @avp это не этап развития цивилизации. это просто старость.

Answer (score 19):

Первые 3 месяца 2018 года:

- [15,791 вопрос задан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2018-01..2018-03+is%3Aq) ([15,105 без закрытых](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2018-01..2018-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0))
- [из них 3,834 вопроса без единого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20created%3A2018-01..2018-03+is%3Aq) ([3,665 без закрытых](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20created%3A2018-01..2018-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0))

Это ~24.3% (~24.3% без закрытых).

За первые 3 месяца 2019 года:

- [16,340 вопросов задано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2019-01..2019-03+is%3Aq) ([15,170 без закрытых](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2019-01..2019-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0))
- [из ниx 6,475 вопросов без единого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20created%3A2019-01..2019-03+is%3Aq) ([6,128 без закрытых](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20created%3A2019-01..2019-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0))

Это ~39.6% (~40.4% без закрытых).

Таким образом, действительно, процент неотвеченных вопросов увеличился в более чем полтора раза (1.63, или 1.66 без закрытых вопросов) за год. И хотя общее кол-во вопросов немного возросло (на ~3.5%, с исключением закрытых и вовсе всего лишь на 0.4%), если тенденция с отсутствием ответов будет сохраняться, это в конечном итоге приведёт и к уменьшению вопросов - никто не будет их задавать, если нельзя получить ответ. Вот такая сухая статистика. Некоторым стоит задуматься о возможных причинах такого проседания.

Как можно видеть, исключение закрытых вопросов демонстрирует ещё б*о*льшие проблемы на сайте. Но в целом влияет на удручающую картину не существенно (если, конечно, не обращать внимания на то, что почти в 8 раз уменьшает величину прироста вопросов).

Для дальнейшего сравнения можно посмотреть цифры по предыдущим годам (без закрытых вопросов) за январь-март:

- 2017 ([12,706 задано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2017-01..2017-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0), [2,336 без ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20created%3A2017-01..2017-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0), ~18.4%)
- 2016 ([9,938 задано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2016-01..2016-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0), [1,479 без ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20created%3A2016-01..2016-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0), ~14.9%)
- 2015 ([3,412 задано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2015-01..2015-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0), [323 без ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20created%3A2015-01..2015-03%20is%3Aq%20closed%3A0), ~9.5%)

В графической форме по годам:

> [image: график по годам]

Видна постоянная тенденция роста отношения вопросов без ответа к общему кол-ву заданных вопросов, но за последний год скорость роста заметно увеличилась.

Comment: В качестве дополнения к ответу: [на сайте есть бот, который удаляет старые вопросы без ответов и с низкой посещаемостью](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2294/177221). Пороги удаления - через 30 дней и через год. Удаленные сообщения не видны в поиске, что очень сильно влияет на числа "всего задано", причем чем дальше в прошлое - тем больше погрешность. Например, [реальное количество вопросов за январь-март 2018](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1032082/) - **22265**, а не **15791**, как утверждается в вопросе. Разница в **30%**. Это в 2 раза больше, чем обозначенный % "ухудшения" :)

Comment: Числа за остальные года так же сильно занижены, причем чем дальше в прошлое - тем больше погрешность. Все графики и все % построены по количеству вопросов заданных в определенном году **и не удаленных к данному моменту**, а вовсе не на "общем кол-ве заданных вопросов". По сути, эти графики показывают, что на сайте есть механизм, который массово удаляет старые непопулярные вопросы без ответа - и нет никаких оснований утверждать, что они хоть как-то демонстрируют "общие проблемы сайта" или "удручающую картину". Автор ответа исправить числа на реальные отказался, сославшись на ... лень.

Comment: @PashaPash я думаю, в отдельном чате можно было бы продолжить дискуссию по этой теме. Поэтому, да, хорошо бы сохранить написанное.

Comment: @ αλεχολυτ восстановил, [перенес в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92604/discussion-on-answer-by---so-).

Comment: на сколько сильно изменился график за год?

Comment: @Danis можете при желании прямо по ссылкам потыкать и увидеть обновлённые значения.

Answer (score 10):

Как вижу ситуацию я:

- На простые и общие вопросы уже давно есть ответы. На такие вопросы интересней всего отвечать (или читать чужие ответы), так как можно научиться чему-то новому и интересному, с чем сталкиваешься каждый день
- На сложные вопросы по не самым распространенным технологиям часто просто некому ответить. Например всё кроме Java/C#/Javascript/C++. Как писали выше, в некоторых метках отвечает в основном 1 человек.
- Вопросы требующие очень обширных знаний в узкой области. Например, вопрос про какую-то библиотеку на C#, или js. Так же некому отвечать. Я пытался несколько раз задать такие вопросы здесь, но в итоге копировал свой вопрос на англоязычный SO и получал ответ относительно быстро
- Про плохие вопросы от новичков уже много написали выше

Получаем замкнутый круг. Даже если у меня будут обширные знания в некоторых технологиях, я очень редко буду встречать хорошие вопросы на эту тему. Люди видят, что на сложные вопросы отвечают редко, и перестают задавать их. Тем, кто может ответить, становится скучно, и они реже отвечают.

Answer (score 5):

Многие уже высказали(и в комментариях и в ответах) примерно мою позицию. Много разных обвинений, но нет предложений. Попытаюсь предложить:

Сложные вопросы задавать бесполезно(ответ просто не получаешь), проще самому разобраться за пару дней. Гуглить по ruSO тоже бесполезно(сложных вопросов то нет).

Меня(думаю и не только) достали тупые вопросы аля "как сделать мою домашку". Я сюда не фрилансить захожу что бы за кого то делать, но я с удовольствием поделюсь опытом, знаниями. Готов потратить часы что бы написать хороший ответ. Но вопросов нет :( Бывают иногда хорошие конкурсные вопросы но очень часто узко специализированные.

Стратегию ответа на 90% вопросов(не считая домашние задания): Ctrl+C(вопрос) -> Ctrl+V(гугл), Click(1-5 ссылка), Ctrl+C(страница по ссылке) -> Ctrl+V(ответ), Profit. Репа ростёт, значки падают. И я не хочу сказать что те кто так делает какие то ужасные люди но почему SO вынуждает меня делать так же или не делать вообще ничего?

Вопрос на который я бы хотел(и мог) ответить это один из тысячи и просто что бы его найти нужно очень постараться. "Интересные" на главной совсем не интересные. Голосов у новых вопросов нет. Даже хотел написать плагин/утилиту для фильтрации вопросов но руки пока не дошли. Но было бы удобно если бы это позволяла делать площадка. Фильтрация примитивная: отображать вопросы участников с репой > 1000. В ленте будет больше качественных вопросов. Основные вопросы задают участники с репой < 100. Репутацию > 1000 не сложно получить стратегией которую я описал выше, но после получение зачем задавать тупой вопрос если и сам можешь найти ответ?

Comment: Что для вас сложный вопрос?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev например вот: простой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/316118/189281 (у меня под рукой было готовое решение), а вот сложный(от того же участника) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428603/189281

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev что бы показать поновее я полистал ленту новых вопросов. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972061/189281 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972032/189281 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972005/189281 . На многие ответить я не могу но у меня есть желание это сделать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev и я сейчас попытался найти нормальный вопрос от участника с маленькой репутаций. Я нашёл https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972031/189281 . Пролистал почти 5 страниц но я это сделал.

Comment: Вы жалуетесь, что «Сложные вопросы задавать бесполезно(ответ просто не получаешь), проще самому разобраться за пару дней.» **Так возьмите и напишите, в чем вы разобрались — вопрос + свой ответ.** И интересных вопросов прибавится, и качественных ответов. И вам  сесть и сформулировать письменно может помочь прояснить картину, и другим людям может помочь. SO **не** вынуждает вас «делать так же (— отвечать на тупые вопросы—) или не делать вообще ничего».

Answer (score 2):

IMHO надо оценивать не число ответов, а число ПРАВИЛЬНЫХ ответов. Т. к. от других ответов толку мало.

Скажем, если на вопрос сразу дается правильный ответ, нет нужды в других ответах, которые будут только мешать.

Как оценивать число правильных ответов - другой вопрос. Очевидно, что не по числу проголосовавших и не по тому, выбрал ли этот ответ задавший вопрос. Для оценки правильности надо обладать глубокими знаниями в области, по которую задаются вопросы и проверять каждый ответ один за другим.

Comment: Мда уж, и каждый из тысяч ответов вручную оценивать?

Comment: А как верифицировать обладание *глубокими знаниями*? Конечно, можно по репутации (по релевантным меткам). В таком случае каждый плюс к ответу должен иметь разную цену в зависимости от репутации плюсующего, а показываемая суммарная оценка ответа  может пересчитываться при каждом показе. Однако, это потребует изменения кода сайта, чего видимо (почти наверняка)  не произойдет

Comment: С наличием же только одного правильного ответа не согласен. Ведь остальные (тоже правильные) могут освещать определенные нюансы задачи, не затронутые в наиболее популярном ответе

Comment: @avp Примитивные вопросы = меньше правильных ответов зачастую. Так что это ещё один момент…

Comment: «от других ответов толку мало» — ой далеко не всегда, бывает и так, что «неправильный» ответ намного лучше «правильного», а «правильный» вообще в минусах сидит, потому что на самом деле неправильный

Comment: @andreymal да, это так.

Answer (score -9):

Пользуясь случаем... Интерес к SO отбивают как устаревшие (неактуальные) правила, так и люди, набравшие  репу по одним вопросам, но совершено не понимающие других, но лезущие модерировать - закрывать, удалить.

Вот конкретно по вопросам [WordPress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) (на сек +60% сайтов на нём) - множество вопросов и ответов было убито именно такими "умниками". Ну не понимаете вопроса или ответа - ну пройдите мимо. Убийством вы не сделаете лучше ни вопрошающим/отвечающим ни SO.

И по правилам. Запрет давать ссылку при разборе css (и нек. др. вопросов) устарел лет на 15. Сейчас сайты делаются на движках и стили находятся в десятках файлов и имеют зависимые правила (как друг от друга, так и от девайсов) - вычленить их просто не представляется возможным. Да и помочь без "визуального контакта" с результатом довольно сложно. В то время как показав сайт и указав на проблему и вопрос решится быстро и помогающим будет легче помогать.

Comment: Ссылку на библиотеку/движок/что-то ещё давать можно. Ссылку на сайт/проект/нерабочий код - нельзя.

Comment: Если разрешить ссылку на нерабочий код - то все вопросы тут мигом окажутся в формате *"мойсайтнеработаитвотвамссылкапамагите!"*.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я о том и говорю - в современном мире это бред. Многие форумы наоборот, требуют ссылку, что бы можно/легче было помочь

Comment: На форумах задача - помочь один раз, вопросы повторного использования советов мало кого интересуют. Тут же мы пытаемся строить базу ответов, на которые можно приходить из гугла и читать повторно.

Comment: На сайте по ссылке ошибка в лучшем случае будет исправлена (в худшем случае - сайт пропадёт), и вопрос станет бесполезным, а вместе с ним - и все ответы.

Comment: Я пояснил почему народу становится НЕИНТЕРЕСНО быть на ruSO. Но вы, можете оставаться при своём убеждении..

Comment: @PavelMayorov не думая, что у форумов именно такая задача — помочь единожды. Иначе бы не было смысла сохранять вообще тред, после решения смело удалять. Задачи, кмк, одинаковые, просто формат и требования несколько разные. Например, на форумах исходное сообщение обычно уже не поправить без модератора, если есть ответы в цепочке, это порождает дискуссию и размывает решение, то есть его дальнейшее восприятие, пришедшими из поисковиков.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну так в формате-то и проблема, формально форумы - кладезь уникальных знаний, а реально эти знания в таком потоке мусора вылавливать приходится...

Comment: Заминусованный ответ только подтверждает мои слова. :) Набрали циферок по сям и прочим алголам,но про web-разработку понятия не имеют. Зато "пузатые", могут командовать... Вот думать бы ещё научиться. Ну да мне что вам де тут жить и верить в светлое будущее.

Comment: По поводу правил и народа, которому неинтересно, вы абсолютно правы, однако, как уже заметил Pavel Mayorov, цели вас и такого народа противоречат целям сайта.

Comment: @SeVlad в этом треде пока что вы тут единственный смотрите свысока на остальных. Повод задуматься.

Comment: @SeVlad заминусованный ответ означает, что несколько участников не согласны с ним, и их больше чем согласных. Это не означает что кто-то захотел по-командовать, это означает что у кого-то есть противоположное мнение.

Comment: @andreymal если подумать.. если совсем немного подумать, то станет понятно, что у всех многопользовательских ресурсов  цели одинаковые (окромя денег владельцам) - собрать комьюнити и помочь ЮЗЕРАМ. С их КОНКРЕТНЫМИ проблемами. Иначе можно было бы просто написать ФАКи и никого не пускать для генерации контента, не париться с  комментами, регой и прочим модерированием.    ЗЫ. радует что кол-во минусов сократилось. Значит не я один понимаю, в чём проблема..

Comment: @SeVlad написать ФАКи - это и есть главная цель Stack Overflow (окромя денег, да). Наглядная демонстрация этой цели - поощрение вопросов с самоответами (есть даже галочка "Ответить на собственный вопрос" на странице создания(!) вопроса). Помощь отдельным юзерам - это *второстепенная* вещь, которая лишь помогает написать ФАКи и способствует наполнению сайта (если никого не пускать, то и писать ФАКи будет просто некому), но не более того. Можно с этим не соглашаться, и вы далеко не единственный, кому это не нравится, но тем не менее Stack Overflow - он такой.

Comment: @andreymal не находишь противотечения в "создавать ФАКи руками юзеров" и "не давать юзерам решать их насущные вопросы"? (К этому прибавлю - отбитие интереса у грамотных юзеров отвечать на вопросы нубов. Как следсвие - это мешает развивать и создавать комьюнити по новым направлениям)

Comment: @SeVlad не нахожу. Есть вопросы, которые помогают юзерам и подходят под формат ФАКа. Есть вопросы, которые помогают юзерам, но не подходят под формат ФАКа. Первые писать здесь нужно, вторые — не нужно. Вот и всё.

Comment: @andreymal не о том речь.. Не о формате ресурса, а об то что (и кто) мешает юзерам получать ответы. И отвечать тоже. Это причина почему людям ресурс становиться неинтересен.

Comment: А  WordPress и верстка какое вообще имеют отношение к программированию? Тем более странно заставлять настоящих программистов подстраивать под нужды верстальщиков и настройщиков вордпресса.

Comment: @Eugene данивапрос! Удалить с ruSO всё, что связано с вебразработкой и делов-то...

Comment: Те, кто действительно что то делает, а не wordpress настраивает пусть остаются, но на положении низшей касты. Чтобы слушали, учились, и не пытались правила навязывать. В противном случае пагубные последствия. Одна привычка формировать текст sql-запроса вместо параметров чего стоит! Даже в MySQL давным-давно были параметры, но с sql-инъекциями борются извращенными способами до сих пор. Мало того - начали для нормальных языков программирования советовать то же самое. И эти ответы выбирают как правильные.